# IE8 fails to properly align stacked floated elements of fixed size

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to float elements of fixed widths (300px + 40px margin), and heights which are integral multiples of a fixed value (400px + 40px margin), so that they should all stack up perfectly.  I am floating them within a container that has a fixed width to fit exactly two in a row (680px = 2*300px + 2*40px).  Non-IE browsers perform this task perfectly, but IE8 fails for reasons I can't fathom.  Can anyone explain why IE8 can't do this seemingly simple task, and if it's possible to fix it, without having to explicitly 'clear: left;' on those elements? (If I add an inline "clear: left;" to that element, IE8 will clear it, but its position doesn't change at all, so it's not like the element is "bumping up" against the "tall" element.)

http://jsfiddle.net/Nun2L/

HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">

  <div class="box tall"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 680px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box.tall {
  height: 440px; 
}
```

Comment: Try adding overflow:auto to #boxes

Answer (score 0):

It could be IE is dropping into quirks mode and .class.class is messing it up.  See:

[IE8 not accepting multiple classes in quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663495/ie8-not-accepting-multiple-classes-in-quirks-mode)